# Is it possible to use single Application Insights instance for a Function App and a Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

Can I use `General` type for my Application Insights instance to capture insights from apps typed as Web App or App Service? Because I want to see insights from my functions app and web app under the same (single) Application Insights instance.

Comment: the "application type" in appinsights really only affects what tools you see in the portal.  the "asp.net" type shows *everything*, some of the others show less.  some of the specific types like HockeyApp or AppCenter require additional configuration, but other than that, the only difference is UI level in the portal.

Comment: I managed to sort things out. But as supposed the merged query results are not as informative as before. I need to assign more informative custom columns using telemetry sdk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible. And I'd even say it's the best approach if the Function and Web App make up the same application. Otherwise tracing information across two separate App Insights instances is a pain in the rear.

Comment: I would like to us same AI instance for this task, however I could not achieve it neither found a relevant setup example anywhere. Have you ever done it, could you point out some pitfalls? thanks.

Comment: Funny you should ask - I only know this is possible because I was Googling around for integration instructions with WebJobs and came across docs on configuring it for Azure Functions. Check this out: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/04/06/azure-functions-application-insights/
Make sure to use the same InstrumentationKey as you do for your Web App.